# GLS regression versus linear mixed models in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, linear-model, random-effects-model, generalized-least-squares

I am looking for papers in the management area that discuss more on the use of linear mixed models in R. Yet all I am getting the results where most, if not all, use GLS regression technique. Would you enlighten me on these two things? I know that that they are similar, such as the case of panel data and unobserved heterogeneity due to random effects.